# Retrieve HDInsight cluster uptime

Tags: azure-hdinsight

Is there a way to retrieve the time at which an HDInight cluster was started or the cluster uptime via the terminal? There seems to be no command or API that I can find that gets the startup timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I could not find a direct command or API to get the cluster uptime.

You can get the HDInsight cluster uptime using Ambari Home dashboard.

> The Ambari UI dashboard (https://.azurehdinsight.net) provides an overview of cluster health, such as **uptime**, memory, network and CPU usage, HDFS disk usage, and so forth.

[image]

Refer: [Manage HDInsight clusters by using the Apache Ambari Web UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-manage-ambari).

Answer (score 0):

There is no **resume**/**Pause** button in HDInsight(unlike Azure Synapse).The billing continues till the time the cluster is active. So cluster-wise, you can only see the Cluster creation date in Azure Portal in **Properties**

[image]

Node-wise you can run the `uptime` command in the specific node to get the timestamp